# Something wrong with chef server

Tags: ruby, nginx, chef-infra, ubuntu-10.04

We are trying to setup chef infrastructure in our environment .
Till now I have install chef server 11.0 and have configured it, but while trying to access web interface with default credentials I'm getting following error,

`we're sorry but something went wrong`

following is some content of access.log file at /var/nginx/access.log

```
 10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:49 -0700]  "GET /users/login HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.016" 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.016" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 680
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:50 -0700]  "GET /assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.004" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.004" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 771
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:50 -0700]  "GET /assets/application-39449c5463355a4c86a07971a900b9f4.js HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.272" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.003" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 755
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:51 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/loading.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.013" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.013" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 757
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:51 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/closelabel.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.018" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.018" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 760
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:52 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.796" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.016" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:52 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/br.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.016" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.016" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:52 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/b.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.806" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.026" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 795
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:52 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tr.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.812" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.032" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:03:52 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/bl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.816" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.037" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:04:02 -0700]  "POST /users/login_exec HTTP/1.1" 500 "0.027" 643 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "500" "0.027" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 855
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:48 -0700]  "GET /users/login HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.189" 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.186" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 680
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:49 -0700]  "GET /assets/application-39449c5463355a4c86a07971a900b9f4.js HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.006" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.006" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 755
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:49 -0700]  "GET /assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.567" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.008" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 771
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:49 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/loading.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.010" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.010" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 757
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:49 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/closelabel.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.051" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.051" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 760
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:50 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/b.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.175" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.007" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 795
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:50 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.175" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.007" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:50 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/bl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.010" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.010" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:50 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tr.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.012" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.012" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:50 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/br.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.233" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.006" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:14:55 -0700]  "-" 400 "5.473" 0 "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 0
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:15:09 -0700]  "POST /users/login_exec HTTP/1.1" 500 "0.321" 643 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "500" "0.321" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 846
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:26 -0700]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 "0.356" 108 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "302" "0.161" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 592
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:27 -0700]  "GET /users/login HTTP/1.1" 200 "0.175" 1133 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "200" "0.175" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 866
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:28 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/closelabel.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.010" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.010" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 950
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:28 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/loading.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "2.304" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.078" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 947
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:28 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.164" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.008" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 986
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:29 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/br.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.010" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.010" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 986
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:29 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/b.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.466" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.010" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 985
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:29 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/bl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.418" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.013" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 986
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:29 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tr.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.720" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.016" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 986
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:20:47 -0700]  "POST /users/login_exec HTTP/1.1" 500 "0.126" 643 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "500" "0.126" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 1062
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:38 -0700]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 "0.100" 108 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "302" "0.093" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 808
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:38 -0700]  "GET /users/login HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.025" 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.025" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 866
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:39 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/closelabel.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.008" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.008" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 950
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:40 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.841" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.008" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 986
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:40 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/b.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.845" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.012" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 985
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:40 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/loading.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.849" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.016" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 947
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:40 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/bl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.852" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.020" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 986
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:40 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/br.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.026" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.026" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 986
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:40 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tr.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.859" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.027" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 986
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:27:54 -0700]  "POST /users/login_exec HTTP/1.1" 500 "0.275" 643 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "500" "0.275" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 1062
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:25 -0700]  "GET /users/login HTTP/1.1" 200 "0.022" 1062 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "200" "0.022" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 896
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:26 -0700]  "GET /assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.003" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.003" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 771
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:26 -0700]  "GET /assets/application-39449c5463355a4c86a07971a900b9f4.js HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.005" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.005" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 755
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:26 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/closelabel.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.004" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.004" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 760
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:26 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/loading.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.007" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.007" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 757
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:26 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.009" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.009" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:26 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/tr.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.014" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.014" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:26 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/bl.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.016" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.016" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:26 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/br.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.016" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.016" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 796
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:26 -0700]  "GET /assets/facebox/b.png HTTP/1.1" 304 "0.023" 0 "https://10.11.60.29/assets/application-34d2931a4024e71f18837a713e905ef6.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "304" "0.023" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 795
10.11.60.29 - - [25/Aug/2016:00:28:35 -0700]  "POST /users/login_exec HTTP/1.1" 500 "0.031" 643 "https://10.11.60.29/users/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" "127.0.0.1:9462" "500" "0.031" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" 846
```

Comment: Check the actual Chef Server logs for something more useful? I forget where they were under Server 11 because it's been a few years since that was obsoleted, but look around under `/var/log` and I'm sure you'll find them. Maybe it was `/var/log/chef-server`?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Now, I have reverted the machine and installed chef-server once again and it's working fine.